# joing the multipale tables into one query

Tags: php, mysql

hello as i discussed yesterday with retrieving data from multiple tables into

multiple queries but i got many good advises for JOIN of tables into one query.

Actually in here i am joining multiple tables into one query but i want to retrieving data

just from two tables T1 is properties and T2 is images of related property.

i did but it gives an error which i couldn't find it.

```
Error Massage : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM       
properties, provinces, districts, pds, propertyimages WHERE Provinces.' 
at line 22



Here is the Query:

"SELECT 
    properties.PropertyID,
    properties.PropertyName,
    properties.PropertyType,
    properties.PropertyDealType,
    properties.PropertyRegion,
    properties.PrepostedPrice,
    properties.PricePerArea,
    properties.DealStatus,
    properties.MoreinfoDealGeneralInformation,
    properties.MoreInfoPropertyGeneralInformation,
    properties.CurrencyType,

    propertyimages.PropertyID,
    propertyimages.ImageName,
    propertyimages.ImagePath,

    Provinces.ProvinceName,
    districts.DistrictName,
    pds.PDName,

    FROM properties, provinces, districts, pds, propertyimages

    WHERE Provinces.ProvinceID=Properties.ProvinceID
    AND   districts.DistrictID=Properties.DistrictID
    AND   pds.PDID=properties.PDID
    AND   properties.PropertyID=propertyimages.PropertyID
    AND   ProvinceName= 'Kabul'
    AND   DistrictName='KabulCity'
    AND   PropertyDealType='For Rent'
    ORDER BY properties.PropertyID";
```

Comment: Do you see a Comma after pds.PDName ? just before the FROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove '**,**' from the line

```
pds.PDName,
```

and better try to join any two tables like

```
FROM properties
JOIN provinces ON provinces.PropertyId = properties.provinceId
```

Comment: Thanks alot got it cause i am new to PHP&MYSQL is it correct forall :          **FROM properties, provinces, districts, pds, propertyimages

    WHERE JOIN provinces ON Provinces.ProvinceID=Properties.ProvinceID
    AND   JOIN districts ON districts.DistrictID=Properties.DistrictID
    AND   JOIN pds ON pds.PDID=properties.PDID
    AND   JOIN properties ON  properties.PropertyID=propertyimages.PropertyID**

Comment: yes but need to consider that,No 2 tables have same column name,if you have like that,you need to select them manually like table_name1.col_name

Comment: whenever i am retrieving the images of one property so its displaying all with repeated property Info. how can i LIMIT one image per property in my query ???

Comment: Try with GROUP BY propertyimages.PropertyID

Answer (score 0):

You have leave the the `,` before the From clause remove it.
At here

```
pds.PDName
```

Like it:

```
districts.DistrictName,
pds.PDName

FROM properties, provinces, districts, pds, propertyimages
```